# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

im trying to use a crystal report to print the current content on my data grid view(it has a filter or a search option) but this error always comes my code is

```
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM tbIngredients WHERE " +
     stcMRP.Selected + " ORDER BY IngredientNo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just send stcMRP.Selected in your SQL query. You will have to translate it like so:

```
string strWhereExpression = "[database column name]=";
if (stcMRP.Selected) strWhereExpression += "1";
else strWhereExpression += "0";


cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM tbIngredients WHERE {0} ORDER BY IngredientNo", strWhereExpression);
```